# String^ declaration in C++

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

As far as I am aware C++ string declaration follows the form:

```
std::string param;
```

I was walking through a code and realised the declaration of string is done this way:

```
System::String^ param;
```

Can anyone share light on this declaration?! Is this Microsoft Visual C++ string declaration or a special library which provides another alternative to using C++ string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI) syntax for a [handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08.aspx) to an object on the managed heap.

Answer (score 10):

It's Microsoft-specific, and is part of a language they call C++/CLI. This syntax declares a Common Language Runtime (CLR) `String` variable (the same kind you get when you declare a `string` in C#). These are not directly interchangeable with the several C/C++ string types, but Microsoft provides marshalling facilities to convert CLR `String` objects to unmanaged strings and vice versa.

C++/CLI enables developers to create programs that bridge regular C++ classes/functions (otherwise called "unmanaged code") with CLR classes/functions (otherwise called "managed code"). Microsoft also exposes lower-level features of the CLR to C++/CLI, some that are exposed to C# too (like pointers), and some that aren't (like finer granularity over member access levels).

It's useful if you want to use an existing C or C++ library in a language like C# (by making the bindings in C++/CLI then exposing them to the CLR without going through P/Invokes), or if you want to port an existing unmanaged C/C++ library or application to a managed environment.

Comment: Well, it doesn't actually create an object.  But the explanation is very good.

Comment: Uh, yeah. Stupid mistake on my end, I'll fix that.